# Issue in concatenation of values

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have wriiten a function like below

```
  function GetCompleteAddress() {
        $('#<%=txtAddress.ClientID %>').val($('#<%=txtWhere.ClientID %>').val() + ', ' + $('#<%=txtCity.ClientID %>').val() + ', ' + $('#<%=ddlState.ClientID %>:selected').text() + ', ' + $('<%=txtZip.ClientID%>').val() + ', ' + $('#<%=ddlCountry.ClientID%>:selected').text());
        $('#fldAddress').hide();
    }
```

After rendering it appears as

```
      function GetCompleteAddress() {
        $('#ctl00_RightContent_PostingEdit_txtAddress').val($('#ctl00_RightContent_PostingEdit_txtWhere').val() + ', ' + $('#ctl00_RightContent_PostingEdit_txtCity').val() + ', ' + $('#ctl00_RightContent_PostingEdit_ddlState:selected').text() + ', ' + $('ctl00_RightContent_PostingEdit_txtZip').val() + ', ' + $('#ctl00_RightContent_PostingEdit_ddlCountry:selected').text());
        $('#fldAddress').hide();
    }
```

It's only adding values upto txtCity, after that it appends undefined in txtAddress.Please help me !!!

Comment: `$('#<%=txtZip.ClientID%>').val()` missing `#`

Comment: show us how your html look like

Comment: have updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the issues:

1) `$('#<%=ddlState.ClientID %>:selected').text()` is wrong selector. you are trying to get select selected. you need to find selected option and then get the text of it.

```
  $('#<%=ddlState.ClientID %>').find(':selected').text()
```

2) Missing id selector `#` for `txtZip`. should be:

```
  $('#<%=txtZip.ClientID%>').val()
```

3) `$('#<%=ddlCountry.ClientID%>:selected').text()` is wrong selector. you are trying to get select selected. you need to find selected option and then get the text of it.

```
  $('#<%=ddlCountry.ClientID%>').find(':selected').text()
```